# How to add a newline function to JSON using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON that I had to manipulate and the code looks like this. I had to manipulate the data because of an invalid part of the data that I could not use when uploading to BigQuery.

```
import json

with open('firetobq_peripheral.json', 'r') as in_file:
    dicts = []
    for line in in_file.readlines() : 
        d = json.loads(line.strip())
        if d.get('Peripherals'): 
            del d['Peripherals']
        dicts += [d]

with open('firetobq_peripheral5.json', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(json.dumps(dicts))
    out_file.write("\n")
```

However `out_file.write("\n")` is not making the JSON write each set of data on a newline like it has in the previous JSONs I have worked on. Does anybody know why this is happening and how to get around this? Thanks for the help.

I need the data to be presented like this

```
{"AppName": "DataWorks", "foundedPeripheralCount": 1, "version": "1.6.1(8056)", "deviceType": "iPhone 6", "createdAt": "2017-04-05T07:05:30.408Z", "updatedAt": "2017-04-05T07:08:49.569Z",  "connectedPeripheralCount": 1, "iOSVersion": "10.2.1"}
{"objectId": "20H5Hg2INB", "foundedPeripheralCount": 0, "DeviceVendorID": "5B7F085E-B3B6-4270-97DC-F42903CDEAC1", "version": "1.3.5(5801)", "deviceType": "iPhone 6", "createdAt": "2015-11-10T06:16:45.459Z", "updatedAt": "2015-11-10T06:16:45.459Z", "connectedPeripheralCount": 0, "iOSVersion": "9.1"}
{"AppName": "DataWorks", "foundedPeripheralCount": 2, "version": "1.6.2(8069)", "deviceType": "iPhone 6s", "createdAt": "2017-04-12T10:05:05.937Z", "updatedAt": "2017-07-06T07:33:02.006Z", "connectedPeripheralCount": 8, "iOSVersion": "10.2.1"}
```

Comment: I think you should do like this  `out_file.write("\\n")`

Comment: Can you please provide an [mcve] with some of your data?

Comment: I have added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to write your data exactly as you have read it in, then you will need to iterate over each dictionary in `dicts`:

```
with open('firetobq_peripheral5.json', 'w') as out_file:
    for d in dicts:
        out_file.write(json.dumps(d))
        out_file.write("\n")
```

If this is not required, then `json.dump` would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("some_file.json", "w") as f: 
    f.write( 
        json.dumps(array_of_dictionaries).replace("},", "},\n")
    )
```